# Laravel get view as array not make it

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

I want to get laravel's views as an array not include them to the view is it possible?

If I use

```
View::make('viewname')->renderSections();
```

it does the job but if I use this function for multiple views it begins to append them.

For example: 
I am creating a module system. Each module has their own view or views. each view has the same sections for getting them into array. Like this

1. View

> ```
> @section('container')
> bla bla bla
> @endsection
> ```

2.View

> ```
> @section('container')
> bla2 bla2 bla2
> @endsection
> ```

when above function in foreach call the views and send the array to top-a.blade.php and top-b.blade.php which are my positions included in master layout.

top a has a section called @section('top-a') $1stview['container'] @endsection like top-b has.

but since above function appending them, top-b overwriting top-a's ['container']. how to not **make** but get the **array** of view's contents

Comment: What's the version of your laravel?

Comment: my laravel version is 5.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Illuminate\View\Factory::getSections()` to get sections as an array. To do this you can simply call the `getFactory` method.

As an example:

```
$sections = View::make('page')->getFactory()->getSections();
```